# Change LiveData reference and update observers

Tags: android, retrofit, android-livedata

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{

LiveData<ApiResponse> liveData;

public SwipeViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    dataSource = getDataSource();

    liveData = dataSource.getLiveData();

}

 public void newRequest(){
        liveData = dataSource.getLiveData();
 }
```

}

I am using retrofit to make api requests and I alos have a custom callAdapter to receive the request response as LiveData, but the problem I'm facing is that when I make a new Request and assign it to the LiveData, the observers are not notified. Is there a way to fix this? Am I doing something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just return `LiveData` from `newRequest` like `return dataSource.getLiveData()`? or you can use a `MediatorLiveData` if you want .

Comment: The thing is that the the request doesnt return the data immediately, so i have to observe the livedata in the activity. I'm not sure that if I keep recalling the method and observing it a new request is created or it just adds observers to the old reference.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do it in my opinion,

1. expose LiveData reference to be observed so that it won't change from anywhere like from ui(activity/fragment).
2. Make one MutableLiveData reference private in ViewModel which will be updated when it's value changed

   ```
   private val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<ApiResponse>()
   val LiveData<ApiResponse> liveData = mutableLiveData

   public void newRequest(){
        mutableLiveData.value = dataSource.getLiveData();
    }
   ```

Comment: I tried doing this but when the mutableLiveData changes the observers dont get notified...